# How to use fonts from window fonts folder for a pdf in Ghostscript?

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript

I am working in a console application in c# in which requirement is to embed a font (present in `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder) in PDF.

I have installed Ghostscript 9.56.1 version and run following commands in command prompt to embed font in pdf.

```
gswin64c -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOPLATFONTS -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sOutputFile=output.pdf -f 1.pdf


gswin64c -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH "-sFONTMAP=C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.56.1/Resource/Init/Fontmap.GS -sFONTPATH#C:\Windows\Fonts" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf -f 1.pdf
```

I have also added following line in Fontmap.GS in the end of file.

```
/MyFont-Regular     (/MyFont-Regular.ttf)   ;
```

Output pdf is produced but font is not imbedded in it instead a default font `NimbuSans-Regular` is imbedded.

[image]

Also what is the font file extension present in Ghostscript font folder ?
How to add a custom font at that location ?

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\Resource\Font
```

I have also tried Itextsharp to embed font but the issue with it was that layout is not maintained when a custom font is embedded in a pdf.

How to embed window 10 installed font in a pdf by using Ghostscript ?

Comment: There's a limitation in the new PDF interpreter in 9.56.1, it isn't honouring FONTPATH and friends. You should either set -dNEWPDF=false, use an old version (9.55.0) or build from current source where this has been fixed. The file extension in the Ghostscript Fonts folder is not relevant. Those are type 1 fonts and adding to that folder on windows will do nothing, because the fonts are built into the ROM file system. You can't 'add a cutom font at that location'. You should use fontmap.GS and cidfontmap. Since you haven't supplied an example I can't tell if your file uses a Font or CIDFont.

Comment: Also, check the licence (AGPL v3) to ensure your intended use is compliant with the terms of the licence.